# pdo connecting problems to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have have a problem connecting to mysql, i have no errors (at least i think i don't), it just gives me a blank page no matter if the connection happens or not. I have this four short files:

init.php:

```
    <?php
session_start();

$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
    'mysql'         => array(
        'host'          => 'localhost',
        'username'      => 'root',
        'password'      => 'pass',
        'db'            => 'ooplr'
        ),
    'remenber'      => array(
        'cookie_name'   => 'hash',
        'cookie_expiry' => 604800
        ),
    'session'       => array(
        'session_name'  => 'user'
        )
    );

spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
    require_once ('classes/' .$class. '.php');
});
require_once ('functions/sanitize.php');
?>
```

config.php:

```
<?php
class Config {
    public static function get($path = null) {
        if($path) {
            $config = $GLOBALS['config'];
            $path = explode('/', $path);

            foreach ($path as $bit) {
                if(isset($config[$bit])) {
                    $config = $config[$bit];
                }
            }
            return $config;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
?>
```

DB.php:

```
<?php
class DB {
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_results,
            $_count = 0;

    public function _construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' .Config::get('mysql/host'). ';dbname=' .Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
        echo ('connected');
    }
    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
?>
```

index.php:

```
<?php
require_once('core/init.php');

DB::getInstance();
?>
```

Comment: Don't know if it can help but in your $GLOBALS, one of your key is 'remenber', I think it should be 'remember'

Comment: where do you call `DB::getInstance()` ? if you don't, your PDO should not exists because your DB constructor is never called.

Comment: Have you checked error logs? or put `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of problematic page and you will see error if exists

Comment: Thanks for that, yes, was nothing to do with this prob thou

Comment: i call 'DB::getInstance()' on the index

Comment: I have no errors, the connection just don't happens

Comment: I found the problem: it should be __construct() and not _construct(). Two underscores instead of one